# In which protocol web server talks to CGI?

Tags: apache-http-server, nginx, network-protocols, cgi, fastcgi

I'm wondering what protocol is used for communication between
web server, e.g. `Apache, Nginx` and `CGI`, e.g. `FCGI, UWSGI`?

Comment: Your question is not clear.  What protocol allows for Apache and Nginx to support CGI, that would be of course, [FastCGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FastCGI).  [WSGU](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_Server_Gateway_Interface) allows for Python support in any application that implements its protocol.  [UWSGI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UWSGI) is one of those implementations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

uWSGI uses the [uwsgi protocol](https://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Protocol.html) (which is somehow related to the WSGI interface, but I'm not sure how), while FastCGI & fgcid use the [FastCGI protocol](http://www.nongnu.org/fastcgi/#id2860531).

Traditional "CGI" didn't have much of a protocol at all – the server would just spawn (fork+exec) the CGI script with HTTP request headers in environment variables (e.g. $HTTP_REFERER), and the script would print a raw HTTP reply to stdout.